# Jquery dialog box visible by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to test a simple dialog box using Jquery UI but somehow the dialog is visible by default.

fiddle-https://jsfiddle.net/kdh85wha/6/

HTML

```
<button id="callConfirm">Confirm!</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {

  $("#dialog").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     buttons : {
          "Confirm" : function() {
              alert("You have confirmed!");            
          },
          "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });

  $("#callConfirm").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });

});
```

Comment: Try adding the class ui-dialog to #dialog. Also your fiddle doesn't include jquery UI so it's not working.

Comment: Fiddle is not working. Kindly add runnable code here.

***https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the jquery version to 1.9 and jquery ui to 1.9 & it is perfectly working

[image: Snapshot]

```
jquery 1.9.1 & jquery ui 1.9.2
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/kdh85wha/7/)

Comment: it works..How did you figure that? very strange, it doesn't work for latest version as well.

Comment: That is exactly what I said.. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a div for the dialog, it must initially be hidden.

```
<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required" style="display: none;">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to this example (https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) the below code is a working example;

```js
var dialog;
$(function() {
dialog = $("#dialog").dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,
     buttons : {
          "Confirm" : function() {
              alert("You have confirmed!");            
          },
          "Cancel" : function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
      });

  $("#callConfirm").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      dialog.dialog("open");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<button id="callConfirm">Confirm!</button>

<div id="dialog" title="Confirmation Required">
  Are you sure about this?
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using older version 1.7.2, just use jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher.